# Mapping over a list of images in Firebase and displaying them in a React component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have images that I have uploaded to Firebase storage and I want to download them again to render them in a component. I saved a list of the names in the Firebase real-time database so that I could use the names to retrieve the images from the Firebase storage.

In componentDidMount I am retrieving the images and then saving them as an array to this.state. When I try to map over the array in my render function, nothing happens. If I console.log(this.state.images) I see the array, but I can't map over it in order to render it.

```js
  export default class Images extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = store.getState();

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
      this.setState(store.getState());
    });
    let photos = [];
    database
      .ref("images/")
      .once("value")
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        let values = snapshot.val();
        let images = [];

        for (var key in values) {
          images.push(values[key]["filename"]);
        }
        images.map(image => {
          // Create a reference to the file we want to download
          const storageRef = storage.ref();
          // Get the download URL
          storageRef
            .child("images/" + image)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(function(url) {
              // Insert url into an <img> tag to "download"
              photos.push(url);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              // A full list of error codes is available at
              // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
              switch (error.code) {
                case "storage/object_not_found":
                  // File doesn't exist
                  break;

                case "storage/unauthorized":
                  // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                  break;

                case "storage/canceled":
                  // User canceled the upload
                  break;
                case "storage/unknown":
                  // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server
                  break;
              }
            });
        });

      });
      this.setState({ images: photos})
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

       {this.state.images && this.state.images.map(image => {
         console.log(image)
       })
       }
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by adding a button to show all images and using a handleClick function that uses the forceUpdate() method to re-render the page.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of unnecessary redirection in your code. You should not need to use `forceUpdate()` to show a list of images in a React component.

1. Create a space in state to store the images

   `state = {
     images: null
   }`
2. Get image URLs and store them in state.

   `componentDidMount() { 
    database
         .ref("images/")
         .once("value")
         .then(snap => this.setState({images: snapshot.val()}) 
         .catch(error => console.error(error))
   }`
3. When URLs become available in state, map over the URLs and render each in an image tag, like you have done.

   `render() {
       return (
         <div>
          {this.state.images && this.state.images.map((image, index) => {
            <img src={image} key={index}/>
          })}
         </div>
       )
     }`

The funky storage ref dance that is happening in your database call is completely unnecessary. You should be storing the downloadURL in your database in the first place. If you are not please log `this.state.images` so we see what you have stored in the database. You just say that you have stored a list of names, I don't understand what you mean by that.